# Broadleaf Commerce in Mobile Interface

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce, spring-mobile

We are using Broadleaf Commerce Frameworks for our E-Commerce Application. I just want to know, 
    How this frameworks is compitable to Mobile Interface? If it is well compitable, I need to know how can we configure the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadleaf Commerce is a server-side framework, but your question is more about frontend design. As far as mobile interfaces go, Broadleaf has no problem dealing with responsive pages or something like Spring Mobile. The only opinion Broadleaf makes about frontend technologies is using Thymeleaf as the templating language as opposed to something like JSP.

The Demo Site heat clinic out of the box is using a responsive design with media queries to modify CSS properties and resize various elements. We would recommend doing your templates this way rather than creating separate mobile templates as the continued maintenance cost of having your template code in 2 places becomes very high.